# App Engine missing

Tags: google-app-engine

When I open my Eclipse, sometimes it shows App Engine is missing and I get several app engine errors. Why is it like I have to remove and add the app engine libraries again and again?
CAn u find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you are using an app engine of latest version or not. If you are using an old version please move to a new version 1.7.3 and check.